# Keras Tensorflow 'Cannot apply softmax to a tensor that is 1D'

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm going over the Book Deep Learning with Python from F. Chollet. 
https://www.manning.com/books/deep-learning-with-python

I'm trying to follow along with the code examples. I just installed keras, and I am getting this error when trying to run this: 
from this notebook:
https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-with-python-notebooks/blob/master/2.1-a-first-look-at-a-neural-network.ipynb

```
from keras import models
from keras import layers

network = models.Sequential()
network.add(layers.Dense(512, activation='relu', input_shape=(28 * 28,)))
network.add(layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
```

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         4 network = models.Sequential()
>         5 network.add(layers.Dense(512, activation='relu', input_shape=(28 * 28,)))
>   ----> 6 network.add(layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/sequential.py in
>   add(self, layer)
>       179                 self.inputs = network.get_source_inputs(self.outputs[0])
>       180         elif self.outputs:
>   --> 181             output_tensor = layer(self.outputs[0])
>       182             if isinstance(output_tensor, list):
>       183                 raise TypeError('All layers in a Sequential model '
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py in
>   **call**(self, inputs, **kwargs)
>       455             # Actually call the layer,
>       456             # collecting output(s), mask(s), and shape(s).
>   --> 457             output = self.call(inputs, **kwargs)
>       458             output_mask = self.compute_mask(inputs, previous_mask)
>       459
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/layers/core.py in
>   call(self, inputs)
>       881             output = K.bias_add(output, self.bias, data_format='channels_last')
>       882         if self.activation is not None:
>   --> 883             output = self.activation(output)
>       884         return output
>       885
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/activations.py in
>   softmax(x, axis)
>        29         raise ValueError('Cannot apply softmax to a tensor that is 1D')
>        30     elif ndim == 2:
>   ---> 31         return K.softmax(x)
>        32     elif ndim > 2:
>        33         e = K.exp(x - K.max(x, axis=axis, keepdims=True))
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py
>   in softmax(x, axis)    3229         A tensor.    3230     """
>   -> 3231     return tf.nn.softmax(x, axis=axis)    3232     3233
>
> TypeError: softmax() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'

I'm wondering if there's something off with my installation?

```
keras.__version__
2.2.4
```

If anyone could give me a clue of what to look into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you have an incompatible Tensorflow version (which Keras is using as a backend). For details look [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/9621)

Comment: Yep, that's what it was. I was using TF version 1.1.0 after updating it to 1.10.0 I don't get that error anymore. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you could try reshape input to (1,actual_shape)